# Passing the callback function as parameter from itself

Tags: javascript, callback

Is it possible for me to pass a callback parameter to another method from within the callback function block itself? Example:

```
var resultCallback = function(result){
   if(result)
   {
       alert('success!');
   }else{
       callServiceB(resultCallback );
   }
}

callServiceA(resultCallback);
```

The reason of this is i wish to workout something like a Chain of Responsibility patterns in javascript.

Tried googled but so far gets nothing. Any idea or comment is welcomed.

Comment: Yes you can. Have you tried it?

Comment: However, putting both the responsibility chain (`callServiceB`) and the resulting action (`alert('success!')`) in the same function is odd/bad practise/design smell. Use a separate callback for the result. It might then look like `callServiceA(orCallServiceB(alertResult))` or `either(callServiceA, callServiceB)(alertResult)`

Comment: actually the case has a lot of calls to other method, i simplified it to 2 for brevity. the logic is like 1. call function a 2. if function a ok, then call function b 3. if function b ok, then call function c, and so on..

Comment: I think my point still applies to that. However, isn't the [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) to call the next function only if the current one failed (couldn't handle the arguments)? What you describe sounds more like monadic chaining (one action *relying* on the previous one) - take a look at [promises](http://promisesaplus.com/) for that

Comment: that looks interesting. btw i just tried and it does work, so can u provide an answer so that i can mark it? need to give credit where it's due :)

Comment: [X] copied comments into an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to pass a callback parameter to another method from within the callback function block itself?

Yes you can. Try it!

> I wish to workout something like a Chain of Responsibility patterns

Putting both the responsibility chain (`callServiceB(resultCallback)`) and the resulting action (`alert('success!')`) in the same function looks like a bad practise/design smell. You should use an extra callback for the result, and separate the declaration of the *chain* from that.

It might then look like `callServiceA(orCallServiceB(alertResult))` or `either(callServiceA, callServiceB, …)(alertResult)`.

> The logic is like 1. call function a 2. if function a ok, then call function b 3. if function b ok, then call function c, and so on.. –  ipohfly 8 mins ago

That doesn't sound like a [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern), where you call the next function only if the current one failed (couldn't process the arguments)? What you describe sounds more like monadic chaining (one action relying on the previous one) - take a look at [promises](http://promisesaplus.com/) for that:

```
 callServiceA.then(callServiceB).then(…).then(resultCallback);
```